# Java synchronization inside run() method

Tags: java, synchronization

Here is my class:

```
public class OnlineDataProcessor implements Runnable
{
    private final Map<String, VehicleData> recentDataMapping = new HashMap<String,VehicleData>();


    public void run()
    {
         //Here i collect data from database and create objects VehicleData and put them in recentDataMapping.
    }

    public String toXML(String vehicleId)
    {
        //Here i take VehicleData object from recentDataMapping and work with it.

    } 
}
```

Then on system startup i have this:

```
OnlineDataProcessor onlineDataProcessor = new OnlineDataProcessor();  
Thread a = new Thread(onlineDataProcessor);
a.start();
```

Then based on servlet requests i have this code:

```
String vehicleId = request.getParameter("vehicleId");
String str = onlineDataProcessor.toXML(vehicleId);
```

So the question is...

Do i need to synchronize access to **recentDataMapping** and **VehicleData** objects inside run() and toXML() methods?

Comment: if you need to user has the very last update, so yest put the map in synchronized block, but if it's not to much important, no it's not necessary while you just read data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using a ConcurrentHashMap, any access to the map should be synchronized since it is a shared resource. You would only need to synchronize that actual addition into the map - all other work can be done outside of a synchronized section.

If you just want to ensure that the code is thread safe, use a ConcurrentHasMap.

Comment: What about the objects that the map is holding?

Comment: The objects that are contained by the map are also part of a shared resource and should be accessed by only one thread at a time. Using a ConcurrentHashMap guarantees that addition and deletion from the map is thread safe, however, any modifications to the objects in the map may not be thread safe. This depends on the object itself, but if it is an object you created, you may consider using a synchronized section when modifying the objects in the map.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Alex is incorrect (cannot vote down because of low rep). Making the map volatile will not help here. You ether need to synchronise reads and writes to the map on the same monitor, or use `ConcurrentHashMap` (assuming you are on Java5 or later)